# Find Confidence Interval by group with python

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to detect outlier in a dataset with car's model and their relative price.

```
lower_bound=0.01
upper_bound=0.99
for i in df.MODEL_DESCRIPTION:
   res=df.where(df.MODEL_DESCRIPTION==i).\
   DOCUMENT_AMOUNT_TOTAL.quantile([lower_bound, upper_bound])
   print(i, res)
```

in this way, I set the interval for the whole data frame on each model, but I would like to do this distinct() per model. I tried to use window (pySpark) or filtering function from pandas but with no success. Thank you in advance for your help!

Data-set Example:

```
  MODEL 7   78176,6
  MODEL 7   92830,86
  MODEL 7   67974,44
  MODEL 3   29951,43
  MODEL 7   71384,22
  MODEL 11  30137,76
  MODEL 2   37135,35
  MODEL 11  40526,74
```

Comment: Why don't you use `groupby`? And what about produce a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Could you edit some example data as text into the question?

Comment: Then you're looping for every entry if you want to use a loop you should try `df.MODEL_DESCRIPTION.unique()`

Comment: @PeterLeimbigler I did it

Comment: @user32185 I tried unique but the output remains the same...

Comment: @PdF do you mind to share `df.head(10).to_dict()`?

Comment: @user32185  Unfortunately I can't, data aren't mine... what kind of information about the data set are you looking for?

Comment: Have you read about [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as I suggested? You can easily create a 10 row dummy `df` that could explain the problem without disclose any sensitive data.